# Couple of questions regarding PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a couple of questions.

I have an algorithm that will generate a couple of pictures in python that must be displayed on a form. I am using PyGt for this. My question is: where should I run my code? Right from the initializer? In that case from what I tested, the form won't show up.

- Should I set up a timer in the
  constructor that starts my algorithm
  half a second later?
- Will running the algorithm freeze my
  form making it impossible to see the
  picture itself? I don't mind that the
  buttons, checkboxes, etc freeze while
  it is computing, as long as the
  current picture is still visible.
- Should I use something like c#'s
  OnFormLoad()? If yes, how can I set
  it? Through connect()?
- How does threading work on python?
  I've heard, but I'm not too sure
  about it, that it was a pain to deal
  with. Is it? In c# it is as easy as
  writing 4 lines. I'd like to use it
  if possible, but if it is going to be
  hard to implement it I can live
  without it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check the [Mandelbrot example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-threads-mandelbrot-example.html).

Basically the idea is to use a worker thread to do the heavy computations (I'd suggest a QThread to ease the communication to the main thread by using signals/slots), then once the work is done emit a signal with the computed data and have the main thread paint it. You can also render the image in the worker thread if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the algorithm in a separate thread, placing the data into a Queue when finished. The main thread (GUI) will periodically sample the queue and display the data when it arrives.